# Set interiors and closures in topological space

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a topological space and let $S\subset X$. Show that $X\setminus \overset{\circ}{S}=\overline{X\setminus S}$.

Also show that $X\setminus\bar{S}=(X\setminus S)^{\circ}$

I want to show these two facts in topological terms rather than metric like I am most used to. Can someone help me at least get started here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X \setminus \overset{\circ}{S}$ is closed (as $\overset{\circ}{S}$ is open by definition) and as $\overset{\circ}{S} \subseteq S$ we also have that

$$ X \setminus S \subseteq X \setminus \overset{\circ}{S}$$ and as $\overline{X \setminus S}$ is by definition the *smallest* closed set containing $X \setminus S$ we have

$$\overline{X \setminus S} \subseteq X \setminus \overset{\circ}{S}$$

On the other hand, $X \setminus \overline{X \setminus S}$ is open, as $\overline{X \setminus S}$ is closed and

$$X \setminus \overline{X \setminus S} \subseteq X \setminus (X \setminus S)=S$$

and as $\overset{\circ}{S}$ is the *largest* open set contained in $S$, we have

$$X \setminus \overline{X \setminus S} \subseteq  \overset{\circ}{S}$$ which implies

$$X\setminus \overset{\circ}{S} \subseteq \overline{X \setminus S}$$ and the two inclusions finish the job.

Comment: Thank you that clarification on open and closed meaning and how to apply it is what i needed

Comment: @BenMorine You're welcome. There is another way using interior points and adherent points of $A$ instead. If you know these notions you could try that method too. For me, primarily, closure = smallest closed superset and interior = largest open subset. So this seems the most natural general solution to me.

Comment: In the last step, did you simply take the compliment of both sides and switch the direction of containment?

Comment: @BenMorine indeed I did. I applied it earlier too.

Answer (score 2):

In general, $A^°$ is the largest open set contained in $A$ and $\overline{A}$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$.

Now, $X\setminus S^°$ is a closed set (complement of open set) and clearly $X \setminus S \subseteq X \setminus S^°$. Thus by the remark above we get $\overline{X\setminus S} \subseteq X \setminus S^°$.

On the other hand, $X\setminus(\overline{X\setminus S})$ is an open set contained in $S$, so we get $X \setminus (\overline{X\setminus S}) \subseteq S^°$. Taking complements, 
$$ X \setminus S^°\subseteq\overline{X \setminus S}$$

and we have proven the desired equality.